# ParseQuery to return file

Tags: android, json, image, parse-platform

I am trying to get a imagefile, basically user's profile image.
I already have store the image to the users table
[image]
Then this is my app

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    navigationItemsList = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();
    addItemsToNavigationList();


    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


    ParseUser userName = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    HEADER_NAME = userName.getUsername();
    HEADER_EMAIL = userName.getEmail();
    mAdapter = new com.charity.dogood.dogood.adapters.NavDrawerAdapter(navigationItemsList, this, HEADER_NAME, HEADER_EMAIL, HEADER_IMAGE);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    //Parse Image and details of the logged in user
    // Locate the class table named "ImageUpload" in Parse.com
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query =  new ParseQuery("User");
    Log.d("Mainactivity", "After query 1");

    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

    Log.d("Mainactivity", "After query 2");
            query.whereEqualTo("username", "bro");
    Log.d("Mainactivity", "After query 3");
    Log.d("Mainactivity", currentUser.getUsername());
    // String usernam = (String)currentUser;

    if(currentUser != null){
        Log.d("Mainactivity", "came to current user check statement");
    query.getInBackground("bro", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {


            if (e == null) {
                ParseFile fileObject = (ParseFile) object.getParseFile("ImageProfile");


                fileObject.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void done(byte[] bytes, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Welcome Back", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

                            // HEADER_IMAGE image = (ImageView) fin
                        } else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage(e.getMessage());
                            builder.setTitle("Sorry");
                            builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                            dialog.show();
                        }

                    }
                });
            } else {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage(e.getMessage());
                builder.setTitle("Sorry");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();

            }

        }
    });
        Log.d("Mainactivity", "After query 4");
}
```

I am able to get the username and email in my drawer like this BUT not the image,

[image]
for the check that I put in here, to check object null-ivty.

```
if (e == null) {
```

I am getting this error message

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are getting 'no results found for query' because the query `ParseQuery("User")` does not search the users class.

Try changing

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query =  new ParseQuery("User")
```

To

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
```

This is how users should be queried according to: https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#users-querying

However I still do not think you need to do a query when you are only interested in the current user:

```
    if(currentUser != null){
        Log.d("Mainactivity", "came to current user check statement");
    currentUser.fetchIfNeededInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {


            if (e == null) {
                ParseFile fileObject = (ParseFile) object.getParseFile("ImageProfile");


                fileObject.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void done(byte[] bytes, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Welcome Back", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

                            // HEADER_IMAGE image = (ImageView) fin
                        } else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage(e.getMessage());
                            builder.setTitle("Sorry");
                            builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                            dialog.show();
                        }

                    }
                });
            } else {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage(e.getMessage());
                builder.setTitle("Sorry");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();

            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Was on my phone when providing the answer, just made an edit, hope that it is more clear

Comment: I think I get what u mean, but what is the query to get the image from the image column?

Comment: What do you mean? If `query.getInBackground("bro",..)` never finds any results then you never get to the code that fetches the image

Comment: Actually if I use u r suggested code, then I will get error in {query.getInBackground("bro", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() , becaues the query is no more and Object type query

Comment: That is true, you will have to change `ParseObject` to `ParseUser`

Comment: Somehow I am getting issue with the brackets and stuff. Would you be kind enough to check all the closing brackets are properly intended, tks

Comment: I am not on my developing PC atm sorry but think it is missing a closing bracket at the very end to close the first if statement perhaps.

Comment: Np :) feel free to ask, otherwise post a new question and point me to it

Comment: here is the new quetsion
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31491507/image-profile-in-imageview-for-navdrawer